# Combine two scopes have same .select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Model person.rb, I have two scopes, both of them are applied independent until now I should combine them.

```
    scope_1, ->(date){
          select("DISTINCT(people.id), people.*, anothertable.ended_at")
         .joins(:anothertable)                                        
         .where("anotertable.ended_at IS NULL OR anotertable.ended_at >= ?", date)}

    scope_2, ->(number){
          select("DISTINCT(people.id), people.*")
         .joins(:thirdtable)                                        
         .where("thirdtable.quantity >= ?", number)}
```

I got error when I code this:

```
   scope = Person.scope_1('2019-01-01')
   scope = scope.scope_2(5)
```

> ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(people.id),
>   people.*

Because there are twice "DISTINCT(people.id), people.*" in SQL.

Question:
In this case, how to verify if scope has already the same "select" ? 
Is there a method in ActiveRecord::Relation do this job ?

Ruby 2.4
Rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

You could add a third scope that only does the `select` part. This is not very elegant though IMO, I would just write a third scope that does what you're looking for in a more sophisticated manner.

```
scope_1, ->(date){
     .joins(:anothertable)                                        
     .where("anotertable.ended_at IS NULL OR anotertable.ended_at >= ?)", date)}

scope_2, ->(number){
     .joins(:thirdtable)                                        
     .where("thirdtable.quantity >= ?)", number)}

scope_select, -> { select("DISTINCT(people.id), people.*") }
```

---

```
scope = Person.scope_1('2019-01-01')
scope = scope.scope_2(5)
scope = scope.scope_select
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but `scope_1` has already used in many place in my project and i don't want to add scope_select everywhere. I try to find a method  do the verification job inside a scope. `if select.exist? nothing else select end`